# Insert into DateField from TextField

Tags: python, postgresql, python-3.x

I recently migrated from **MySQL** to **PostgreSQL**. In my database I have two tables

- one with all TextField columns (extracted data from webpages)
- second with specific-type columns like Date, Int, etc.

How I can copy date from **TextField** (in format *2016-1-20*) to the **DateField** with SQL?

It was working fine with MySQL but with Postgres I am getting this error:

```
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: column "date" is of type date but expression is of type text
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The plain SQL statement would be something like this:

```
INSERT INTO specificTable (dateColumn)
  SELECT textField::date
  FROM textTable
  WHERE ...
```

PostgreSQL has many casting options (the `::date` clause in this case). If the automatic cast does not work for your text format you can use the [date/time formatting functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-formatting.html) that let you specify a template, specifically `to_date()` and `to_timestamp()`.

Comment: Working :) Thanks a lot